# Remove address validation on paypal card payment page

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I want to remove  address validation  on paypal  card payment page  .
please check the image below .I want only fill 
**Card number,Payment types ,Expiration date and CSC** .
please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove that in the PayPal checkout page.It is mandatory.